# Determining which resistors to use in a common-base amplifier

Tags: amplifier, resistors, bjt, npn, common-base

The assignment is to design a common-base amplifier from a supplied schematic, and quite frankly amplifiers are a significant weakness of mine.

Given:

- Small-signal voltage gain A_V≥50  V⁄V
- Input resistance R_in=75Ω
- Peak output voltage swing without distortion ≥2V
- β_F=90
- V_A=800V

[image: Schematic]

Based on my hand calculations I've got:

- g_m=1/75 S
- I_C=346.666 uA
- r_o=2.308 MΩ
- I_B=3.852 uA
- I_E=350.5 uA

But I still have no idea what to pick for R1 and R2. I want to see what the underlying math is.

Answer (score 1):

Good job so far.  Going off your calculations, you already have the emitter current.  All of this current has to flow through R1 (there's no other DC path) so R1=[V(emitter)-VEE]\I_E.  Assuming a 0.7V base-emitter voltage (depends on doping as well as current), you'd have -0.7V at the emitter; 9.3V/351uA=26.5kOhm.

To bias the collector for max output swing, you'd want it at about VCC/2, so it can swing +-VCC/2 without clipping.  That gives you 5V, and since you know your collector current, R2=(VCC-5V)/IC =5V/347uA = 14.4kOhm.

As a quick check, A=gm*(R2//R3)=(1/75)S*12.6kOhm=178, which is well over 50.

Hope this helps!

Edit: I missed the series resistance with the input.  This is 75 Ohms, and the input resistance to the emitter is also 1/gm= 75 Ohms, meaning you get a 0.5x voltage divider from your source to the emitter voltage.  This cuts your total gain in half, so you'd get a gain of 89 or so instead of 178.

Comment: R2 / R3 is NOT 12.6kO. What is going on with that line?

Comment: Also according to equations for common-base amplifiers (https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/common-base-amplifier.html), A_V = alpha(R_C/R_E), so the ratio from collector to emitter theoretically ought to be about 51:1.

Comment: @StarSword thanks for bringing the input resistance to my attention; the voltage gain from emitter to collector is actually RC/r'e in the source you described, which is the number I got.  RC/RE is true for a different set of assumptions